# Why there are two graphical virtual terminals in Fedora 24?

Tags: fedora, xorg, tty, wayland

Both `tty1` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and `tty2` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) provides graphical login screen whereas in previous version there was only one graphical virtual terminal. Why was the second graphical VT added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tty1` is operated by Wayland and `tty2` by Xorg.

```
# lsof /dev/tty1
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-l 1101 root   22u   CHR    4,1      0t0 1042 /dev/tty1
gdm-wayla 1422  gdm    0u   CHR    4,1      0t0 1042 /dev/tty1
# lsof /dev/tty2
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-l 1101  root   24u   CHR    4,2      0t0 1043 /dev/tty2
gdm-x-ses 1872  user    0u   CHR    4,2      0t0 1043 /dev/tty2
Xorg      1874  user    8u   CHR    4,2      0t0 1043 /dev/tty2
```